# Can we have an updated beta (TestFlight) app?

Tags: support, ios-app

The Stack Exchange beta iOS app distributed over TestFlight <strike>will expire in 2 days</strike> has expired. After the 100 day test period, the app won't start any more so all beta testers can't use the app then.

Can we please get an updated release so we don't have to remove the app and install the current release from the App Store instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Brian's answer](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6403648#6403648) in chat we won't see new beta version soon:

> I'm just gonna say switch back to the production version of the app at this point. I don't see 1.7 shipping any time in the foreseeable future. If I do end up getting a bug fix release out, it'll probably be based on the current 1.6 series.