# Is SE Android app Beta over?

Tags: support, android-app

What is the current status of SE Android App **Beta**? Is it still active?

Comment: There is no active or planned development for either versions of the SE app.

Comment: Related, for iOS: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301656/can-we-have-an-updated-beta-testflight-app

Comment: I'm an active user of the app.  At this time does it mater if I stick with Beta or switch to "official" version?

Answer (score 2):

The apps (both iOS and android) are officially frozen. Their status is not Beta, just "frozen".

This is confirmed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/152859) by the former mobile app team leader:

> New feature work on the apps has pretty much been frozen for the time being